# In .net, how can I download this remote file

Tags: javascript, .net, rss, cross-domain

I am trying to build a marquee that reads from a remote rss feed.  The ajax request was failing due to what I can only assume are cross domain restrictions.  Here is my code:

```js
  $(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://www.theleafchronicle.com/section/news01&template=rss_weblogs&mime=xml',
      dataType: 'xml',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function (xml) {
        $(xml).each(function () {
          var title = $(this).find("title").text();
          var des = $(this).find("description").text() + ' - ';
          var wrapper = "<span class='single-feed'></span>";

          $(".feed-container").append($(wrapper).html(des));
        });
      },
      error: function (err) { }
    });
  });
```

This code failed, so I instead tried downloading the xml locally and it worked.  My only concern now is how can I download this code via batch file or possibly a .net executable?  I have tried the System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile method and it brings back a page instead of the intended xml.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
        wc.DownloadFile("http://www.theleafchronicle.com/section/", "theleafchronicle.xml");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wc.DownloadString(url)` or `wc.DownloadData(url)` depending how you prefer the response.

Comment: Of course,  if you prefer an xml document you can also use 
`var xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(url);`

Comment: Close, but no cigar.  It redirected to a generic xml response page, different from what you would get if you were to visit the link specified in the ajax request.